# Target framework in output file name from C# when using multi targets

Tags: c#, msbuild, visual-studio-2017, csproj

When I compile a C# application, the filename of the output is **ProjectName.dll**.
But how do I do if I want the filename to be **ProjectName.net46.dll**?

**Edit**

I want that the outputs to be **ProjectName.net46.dll** and **ProjectName.net40.dll** if I use `<TargetFrameworks>net46;net40</TargetFrameworks>`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MSBuild override output file name](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7489902/msbuild-override-output-file-name)

Comment: I have seen that question, and have try to use it. But I can't figure out how I should change it to fit my needs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some investigations, I found [this line](https://github.com/maddin2016/msbuild/blob/master/src/XMakeTasks/Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets#L124). Based on this, the solution turn out to be as simple as this:

```
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFrameworks>net4.0;net4.6</TargetFrameworks>
    <AssemblyName>$(MSBuildProjectName).$(TargetFramework)</AssemblyName>
  </PropertyGroup>
```

With this solution, both the *.exe, *.dll and *.pdb files are geting the new name. And this solution also make debugging and unit testing work.